# Регулярка, только пробелы \s, исключая \n

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, pcre

Пытаюсь заменить в строке пробелы повторяющиеся два и более раза на одинарные, вот так:

```
$str=preg_replace("/\s{2,}/"," ",$str);
```

Но параметр \s заменяет не только пробелы, но и символы перевода строки `\n` причем на пробел, а мне нужно только пробелы и табуляции. Как сделать?

Comment: А вы действительно что-то кроме пробелов еще "сжимаете"? А то они вам сейчас насоветуют тут ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант 1. Напишите символы явно - пробел и табуляцию

```
$str=preg_replace("/[ \t]{2,}/"," ",$str);
```

Вариант 2. Строку разделить на кусочки (split/exlode) по переводу строки. Каждую строку обработать и потом сделать join. Выглядит немного странно, но зато поможет решить проблему вида "у меня есть пробелы в начале и конце строки, как и их удалить?".

Answer (score 3):

Как насчет того, чтобы указать в регулярке пробел?

```
$str = preg_replace("/ {2,}/", " ", $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один способ: https://ideone.com/rI37yg

```
$str = preg_replace("/((?!\\n)\\s)+/", " ", $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

В регулярных вырадениях PHP горизонтальные пробельные символы можно найти с помощью `\h`:

```
$str = preg_replace("/\h{2,}/u", " ", $str);
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/LosOff/1).

[PHP-демо](https://ideone.com/di7C8N):

```
$re = '/\h{2,}/u';
$str = "Мы  нашли\nпробел,          табулцию,   ещё    один пробел\nконец.";
echo preg_replace($re, ' ', $str);
```

Результат:

```
Мы нашли
пробел, табулцию, ещё один пробел
конец.
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю в коллекцию ответов свой вариант:

```
$str = "Text test    \n  ert Text test  \n  ";

echo preg_replace('~\p{Z}{2,}~', ' ', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Может кому то поможет `str.replace(/[ ][ ]+/g, '')` удалит все пробелы от 2 и  больше, соответственно `str.replace(/[ ]/g, '')` удалит все пробелы из строки.